# Proccess Dialog não abre AsyncTask

Tags: android, asynctask, dialog, progress-bar

Durante uma interação com API que dura em média 5segundos, preciso colocar um Process Dialog.

Meu código:

```
public class finalizaPedido extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Integer> {

    private String retorno;
    private String url;
    private String param = "?";
    private View view;

    public finalizaPedido(View v) {
        view = v;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading...","Loading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer pedID) {
        pd.dismiss();

        view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), ActivityPedidoFinalizacao.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String lojaid = (String) params[0];
        String carrinhoid = (String) params[1];
        String formapagamento = (String) params[2];
        String qtdparcela = (String) params[3];
        String frete = (String) params[4];
        String idbonus = (String) params[5];
        String endid = (String) params[6];
        String previsaoentrega = (String) params[7];

        url = "http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/JustForMoms/Pedido/FinalizaPedido/" + lojaid + "/" + carrinhoid + "/" + formapagamento + "/" + qtdparcela + "/";

        param += "isApp=true";

        if (!frete.equals("")) {
            if (!param.equals("?")) param += "&";
            param += "frete=" + frete;
        }

        if (!idbonus.equals("")) {
            if (!param.equals("?")) param += "&";
            param += "idbonus=" + idbonus;
        }

        if (!endid.equals("")) {
            if (!param.equals("?")) param += "&";
            param += "endid=" + endid;
        }

        if (!previsaoentrega.equals("")) {
            if (!param.equals("?")) param += "&";
            param += "previsaoentrega=" + previsaoentrega;
        }

        webclient client = new webclient(url.replace(" ", "%20") + param.replace(" ", "%20"));
        retorno = client.getmodel();

        if (retorno != null) {
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(retorno);
            } catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Houve um problema na criação do seu pedido. Por favor tente novamente e caso o problema persistir, entre em contato com a Equipe do Blubalu.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Acontece que eu clico no botão que chama a task, mas o process dialog não aparece. Ele só quando a requisição termina, e já redireciona para a próxima pagina.

Comment: Por questões de segurança não deve colocar o IP.